# How to determine 1000000th primitive number in less than 10 minutes in java?

Tags: java

I need code to determine the 1000000-th primitive number in less than 10 minutes. I have written the class below, but it is not as fast as I need it to be. How to optimize this class to improve it's speed of calculation? You can use this class by calling the `get_thPrimitive(int number)`. That will return a long.

```
public class PrimitiveF
{
    // this is our class named PrimitiveF
    private static boolean isPrimitive(long n) 
    {
        //isPrimitive method is a private static method that is used in get_thPrimitive method
        //this method tells us if the number is primitive or not 
        long p=(long)Math.sqrt(n);//here we get square of the input number

        int i=2;
        while(i<=p)//now we check the nember is primitive or not if it is primitive we'll return true
        {
            int k=0;
            for(int j=2;j<=i;j++)
                if(i%j==0)
                    k++;
            if(k==1)
            {
                if(n%i == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static long get_thPrimitive(int n)//get_thPrimitive method is a public static //method
    {
        //this method would give us the Xth primitive number
        int count=0,i=2;
        while(count < n)
        {
            if(isPrimitive(i))
                count++;
            i++;
        }

        return --i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Buy faster hardware :)

Comment: Whats a primitive number? does it live in a cave and eat dinosaur steaks?

Comment: @vikingsteve Looking at the code, he probably meant prime.

Comment: I don't know what a primitive number is. Maybe you refer to [Primitive **Abundant** Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_abundant_number)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Asking someone to write your code for you is discouraged (where "discouraged" is an understatement). Try to rewrite this question in terms of what you've tried to improve performance and why it didn't work. Also see the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for advice on writing good questions. Good luck.

Comment: The first Google result for "determine if a number is prime" is this helpful article: http://www.wikihow.com/Check-if-a-Number-Is-Prime which details 4 methods for doing it, with varying levels of performance.

Comment: Well, 3 now that I removed an incorrect one. :P

Comment: @jpmc26 He's new, but he did post working code, showed what he'd tried and asked for suggestions about what else to try.  How is that not a valid question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing and improving code and should be asked on [Code-Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The answer is simply: Use a better algorithm. Personally I would keep a list of prime numbers and only divide by prime numbers (if you can divide by 6, you could already divide by 2 or 3, both prime numbers), pre-fill it with 1 and 2, and only test odd numbers. There are probably more efficient methods out there though.

Answer (score 2):

You return false from that isPrimitive() method if and only if n has no prime divisiors.  To do that, you generate all primes up to sqrt(n)...but you are using many inner prime tests just to perform just one larger one, and you are using a slow method for those inner prime tests.

If the code is correct, but just too slow, then you can get a huge speedup by just:

1. If n is even then return true if n is 2 or false for any other even number.
2. In your loop, test only odd divisors starting at 3 and less than or equal to sqrt(n)+1. Do not worry if these are prime divisors or not.  It doesn't matter, and testing the divisors for primeness only slows you down.

If n is odd and has no odd divisors detected above, then it is prime.

That will drastically speed up your code.  If that still isn't fast enough, you can investigate using a Sieve algorithm.  The basic method is due to Eratosthenes in ancient times and is described at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 2):

If by primitive you mean prime (I have seen the terms used interchangeably), you're using one of the slowest algorithms. Search "sieve", perhaps "quadatric sieve" for a much faster solution.

Edit:
Oh, for the sieve, you'll need an array of size 16,000,000 (the millionth prime is a a bit shy of 15.5M).